# How to avoid data loss for non translatable fields if original language is deleted?

Tags: 8

A small scenario to describe an issue:

I have a CONTENT TYPE with 5 fields.

Steps followed:

1. Go to admin/config/regional/content-language.
2. Enable translation for only 2 fields.
3. Then created a node in the german language(original language) and also added translation for the FRENCH language.

Now my site doesn't require the German language(original language). So if I remove the german language completely from the site then I lose data for the non-translatable fields which were initially added in the german language.

Above issue occur for all entities. Is there any way I can remove language without losing any data?